# Layout breaks upon refresh using react

Tags: reactjs, solidity

Im building a website using React JS and each time I refresh the page the layout breaks. What could be causing this?[This is before refresh](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jmSUI.png)

[This is after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iFbXX.png)

Comment: Can you share your folder structure and the file where you have imported the css

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In the `public/index.html` call your `style.css`:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/css/style.css" />
```

[image: Folders sample]